# Why stored procedure in mysql return data without OUT parameter with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

Please see line two [24.2.1 Stored Routine Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html)

" A procedure is invoked using a CALL statement (see Section 13.2.1, “CALL Statement”), and can only pass back values using output variables."

I using laravel and call procedure.
laravel

```
$response = DB::select('CALL get_data');
```

procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_data`()
BEGIN
SELECT name, gender, residence, introduce FROM users;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And $resopnse have data!!!

It's curious.

I didn't use out parameter.

pleace teach me .

Comment: what results are you getting? more than just an empty array?

Comment: I got data of database right.

Comment: select statements return results so it seems expected

Comment: using select and procedure is bad way? shold i use out parameter?